# How can I use the roles() or getRoles() functions from the Laravel romanbican/roles package

Tags: class, laravel, acl

I new to OOP so I'm trying to learn how to use the romanbican/roles package.

I have been able to do most things. There is a function roles() and a function getRoles() to return all the roles or the roles of the current user. I'm not sure how to implement them.

```
$rolesobj= new \project\User();
$allroles = $rolesobj->allRoles();
$view->with('roles',($allroles));
```

this is saying that:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::allRoles() (View:`

I'm not sure how to implement the functions above which are in the trait in the User model...just confused...

Answer (score 1):

`$user->roles()` is enough to get all the roles related to a user.
Since your user doesn't exist and doesn't have an `id` you cannot find any roles.

When it comes to the error you're getting:

It simply says that there is no function called `allRoles`.

```
/**
 * Get all roles as collection.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return (!$this->roles) ? $this->roles = $this->roles()->get() : $this->roles;
}
```